# Flutter Stepper horizontal type not working

Tags: dart, flutter, stepper

I have a problem with changing the Stepper type from vertical to horizontal.

This is my code:

```
body: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: data == null ? 0 : 5,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return new Card(
          //child: new Text(data[index]["title"]),
          child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stepper(
          steps: my_steps,
          type: StepperType.horizontal,
          controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
              {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
            return Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: null,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: null,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          //type: StepperType.horizontal,
        ),
      ));
    },
  ),
```

After I uncomment the type I get this error:

> I/flutter (10148): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
>   ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   (10148): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   I/flutter (10148): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming
>   height constraints are unbounded. I/flutter (10148): When a column is
>   in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for
>   example if it is I/flutter (10148): in a vertical scrollable, it will
>   try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
>   I/flutter (10148): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates
>   that the child is to expand to fill the remaining I/flutter (10148):
>   space in the vertical direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ListView` has unbounded heigh so it doesn't know how much space to use for each child, which is a `Stepper`.
Give it some constraints, such minimum height size for each and you should be fine.

```
 (...)
 ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 200.0),
              child: Stepper(
                steps: my_steps(),
                type: StepperType.horizontal,
 (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SizedBox() or Container() widget and set it height

```
SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: Card(
        //child: new Text(data[index]["title"]),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Stepper(
              steps: my_steps(),
              type: StepperType.horizontal,
              controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                  {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                return Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: null,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: null,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              //type: StepperType.horizontal,
            ),
          )),
    )
```